# How can I get the data fields from subclass not superclass?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a super class named `TestSuper`

```
public class TestSuper {
  int a = 0;
}
```

and I have 2 sub classes named `TestSub` and `TestSub2` that extend `TestSuper`

```
public class TestSub extends TestSuper{
   int a=1;
}

public class TestSub2 extends TestSuper{
   int a=2;
}
```

in my main class i created a method that takes in a type `TestSuper` and returns the a value of it and in the main i display it on the console

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args){

    System.out.println(test(new TestSub())+" "+test(new TestSub2()));
}
public static int test(TestSuper b){
    return b.a;
}
}
```

but the output is "0 0" instead of "1 2", what do I do?

Comment: You can only override methods in subclasses.  You cannot override fields.

Comment: just add a constract in you sub classes `TestSub(){ a = 1;}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cast the reference so say which one you want.

```
public static int test(TestSuper b){
    return b instanceof TestSub ? ((TestSub) b).a :
           b instanceof TestSub2 ? ((TestSub2) b).a :
           b.a;
}
```

If this seems needlessly complicated, it is. You should use polymorphism instead.

```
public class TestSuper {
    int a = 0;
    public int getA() { return a; }
}

public class TestSub extends TestSuper {
    int a = 1;
    public int getA() { return a; }
}

public class TestSub2 extends TestSuper {
    int a = 2;
    public int getA() { return a; }
}

public static int test(TestSuper b) {
    return b.getA();
}
```

Comment: so if you redefine the field in the subClass and cast the instance of the subClass to the superClass the value return is the value of the superClass but if you ask for the value by a method or getter the value is return is the value of the subClass!! didn't know that and now i wonder why?

Comment: @Charif non static methods follow inheritance, fields do not.

Comment: now i'm imagening that and instance of subclass containing two field with the same name but diffrent values. is that what is happening

Comment: i read your blog about memory leak is that a memory leak because in this example he will never use a = 0; but is always there

Comment: @Charif yes. The field name notionally includes the declarating class.

Comment: @Charif it's not what is usually meant by a memory leak but you could say that it is.

Answer (score 0):

First understand the difference between hiding and overriding: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html

Then create a getter method in the base-class which you can override in the subclass.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into the theory behind this, and then do the only reasonable thing -forget about writing such kind of code.

In good OOP you consider your fields to be part of your "secret" internal implementation. You don't use fields of sub classes in the super class context. Period.

You are even very conservative about making a field protected in the superclass and to use that in subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

When you call test method like this:

```
test(new TestSub())+" "+test(new TestSub2())
```

You use upcasting. Upcasting seperates interface and implementation for an object. But for seperating interface and implementation and achieving true implementation in polymorphism, you must use polymorphic structures. The instance variables aren't polymorphic. Because of this, actually you call a variable which is in `TestSuper` class.

Only instance methods are polymorphic.